# Get Last-Modified date of a file using JS XMLHttpRequest() on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Here is my problem.

I'm developing an webapp, written in Angular and NOT jQuery, for a client that need to have its database refreshed every week with new sets of data. So they chose to use SQLite3 because they can drop the new DB into a folder and the sales rep can download this DB file every Monday. But there are a series of data that gets cached on localStorage and those data need to be refreshed as soon as the iPad checks the DB file and returns true if is a new file. So, I'm using XMLHttpRequest() to check the head for the "Last-Modified" date and it works perfect on Chrome and Safari, but once I build the app and move to iPad, the Last-Modified date return null. I searched everywhere in the web to try find what could be wrong, but I just could not find any satisfactory answer:

The code I'm using is

```
    var dbPath = "db/myDb.sqlite";
    var getMTime = function(url, callback) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('HEAD', dbPath, true); 
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          var mtime = new Date(xhr.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified'));
          if (mtime.toString() === 'Invalid Date') {
            callback(); // dont want to return a bad date
          } else {
            callback(mtime);
          }
        }
      }
      xhr.send();
    };
```

Thanks in advance for the help

**UPDATE**

Looks like the IOS WebView wipes the HEAD object response... So, thats why by running `xhr.getResponseHeader` I get empty object, but I would love to know if there is an alternative for that and why this object is being wiped...